# restler multiple routes

Tags: php, rest, restler

Im having problems with multiple routs, some of them not working.

```
/**
 * 
 * @url GET /fetch
 * @url GET /fetch/lazyload/:lazy
 * @url GET /fetch/:id/
 * @url GET /fetch/:id/lazyload/:lazy
 * @url GET /fetch/start/:offset/limit/:limit
 * @url GET /fetch/start/:offset/limit/:limit/lazyload/:lazy
 * @url GET /fetch/start/:offset/limit/:limit/sort/:sort
 * @url GET /fetch/start/:offset/limit/:limit/sort/:sort/lazyload/:lazy
 * @url GET /fetch/start/:offset/limit/:limit/sort/:sort/orderby/:order
 * @url GET /fetch/start/:offset/limit/:limit/sort/:sort/orderby/:order/lazyload/:lazy
 */
protected function fetch($id = null, $offset = 0, $limit = 25, $lazy = false, $sort = 'asc', $order = null){
    //override
    throw new RestException(501);
}
```

For instace

```
@url GET /fetch/start/:offset/limit/:limit
```

will not work if url `/fetch/start/1/limit/2`
but it will work if  `/fetch/start/1/2`

and 
`/fetch/:id/` will override    `/fetch/lazyload/:lazy`

so `/fetch/lazyload/true` will not work, the recognized pattern will return  `/fetch:id => lazyload`

am I missing something, or this kind of mappings are not possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ambiguity is playing its part here! read [this thread](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/issues/10) to understand more

In short, parameters in the url are greedy so we need to make sure they come after non greedy urls

For example lets talk about two urls

1. `simple\:param`
2. `simple\name`

if we keep the urls in the same order as above and call `simple\name`, only api method that is mapped to `simple\:param` will receive it setting param as "name". We can fix this by simply changing the order to

1. `simple\name`
2. `simple\:param`

Similarly you can fix your api with the following

```
/**
 *
 * @url GET /fetch/start/:offset/limit/:limit/sort/:sort/orderby/:order/lazyload/:lazy
 * @url GET /fetch/start/:offset/limit/:limit/sort/:sort/orderby/:order
 * @url GET /fetch/start/:offset/limit/:limit/sort/:sort/lazyload/:lazy
 * @url GET /fetch/start/:offset/limit/:limit/sort/:sort
 * @url GET /fetch/start/:offset/limit/:limit/lazyload/:lazy
 * @url GET /fetch/start/:offset/limit/:limit
 * @url GET /fetch/lazyload/:lazy
 * @url GET /fetch/:id/lazyload/:lazy
 * @url GET /fetch/:id/
 * @url GET /fetch
 */
protected function fetch($id = null, $offset = 0, $limit = 25, $lazy = false, $sort = 'asc', $order = null)
{
    //override
    throw new RestException(501);
}
```

HTH